# variable scope in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript

I've built the function to return some variable. But my function uses another function asynchronously.

```
function getVariable() {
  var myVariable;
  asyncronousFunction(function(...){

    myVariable = ...

  });
  return myVariable;
}
```

The problem is that `myVariable` outside of and inside in `asyncronousFunction` are different variables. So I can't assign value to `myVariable` from asynchronous function.

How to resolve this scope problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are *the same* variable, but you cannot `return` the result of an asynchronous function call synchronously from your `getVariable` function. The value of `myVariable` will be updated asynchronously at some unspecified later point in time. But your function is returning the value *now*. That doesn't work.

That means your `getVariable` function is asynchronous as well, which means you have to design it that way. For example it could accept a callback, just like `asyncronousFunction` does.

Answer (score 4):

They are **not different** variables, it is the same variable... but you haven't assigned a value to `myVariable` before you `return` it at the end of the function.

The correct pattern here would be for `getVariable` and `asychronousFunction` to accept callbacks, which are executed when the `asynchronousFunction` has finished executing.

```
function getVariable(callback) {
  var myVariable;
  asyncronousFunction(function(/* pass callback as one of the parameters */){

    myVariable = ...

  });

  // Don't return myVariable, as it's useless at this point
};

function asyncronousFunction(callback) {
   // This simulates the asynchronous call. When the call finishes, invoke callback and pass the result as a parameter.
   setTimeout(function () {
        callback("result");
   }, 1000);
}
```

You should then edit how you **use** the function `getVariable()`.

So where you might have had:

```
var value = getVariable();
// do whatever with value
value++;
```

You should now have:

```
getVariable(function (value) { // value is now passed as a parameter
    value++;
});
```