# Can't query mongoDB with mongoose in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a collection in my mongoDB: `db.co`
and only have one document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d083e32cdcf7ce065b616c"), 
  "age" : 22, 
  "friends" : [ "Tom"], 
  "location" : "NY", 
  "name" : "lee", 
  "skill" : [ "javascript", "java" ] 
 }
```

Then I want query it in `node.js` with `mongoose` through this code:

```
var coSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    age: Number,
    friends: Array, 
    location: String,
    name: String,
    skill: Array
})

var Co = mongoose.model('Co', coSchema);
function findSomeoneInCo (name) {
  Co.find({"name": name}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('find some one failed: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('find successed: ' + doc);
  })
}

findSomeoneInCo("lee");
```

But it return me nothing

What's problem with my code? How can I get the corrent query result?

Comment: .find() is asynchronous. The console.log should work though - do they?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206223/variable-scope-in-asynchronous-function

Comment: @MaxGherkins: Yes, it work in normal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoose pluralizes the lower-cased model name when determining the collection name to use.  So with a model name of `'Co'` it's going to be looking in the `cos` collection by default.

To override the default and align with your existing `co` collection:

```
var Co = mongoose.model('Co', coSchema, 'co');
```

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose pluralizes your model name during any CURD operation, 
Use this & check :

```
var Co = mongoose.model('Co', coSchema, 'co'); //Even the case matters
```

or

```
var coSchema = new Schema({
    age: Number,
    friends: Array, 
    location: String,
    name: String,
    skill: Array
}, {collection:'co'});
var Co = mongoose.model('Co',coSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

.find() works asynchronous, meaning that its callback runs when your function already has.

see [variable scope in asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206223/variable-scope-in-asynchronous-function)

```
//try passing a callback function to your search function, like:
function findSomeoneInCo (name, callback) {

  //happens now - here you could still return something

  Co.find({"name": name}, function (err, doc) {

   //happens later - too late to return stuff, function has ran already

    if (err) {
        callback(err);
        return;
    }
    callback(doc);
  })
}


//call your function passing a callback function
findSomeoneInCo("lee", function(doc){
  console.log('do something with your results: ' + doc);
});
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it doesn't success.In fact, the first way without callback, I can query another collection's data.Just can query this one

Answer (score 1):

I notice your callback to find() has the following parameters : err, doc

find() always returns an array so you really want this to be : err, docs

OR
use findOne()

The async stuff shouldn't be a problem in the code you've posted, the nested callbacks will still be executed. Are you sure your connection is OK. I would run an open query :

```
Co.find({}, function(err, docs){
 console.log(docs);
}
```

Just to check the collection has something in it